# How to pass a Comparator to a custom quick sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, quicksort, comparator

Whenever I run my test program it will run up until it gets to the `personQueue.sort()` at which point it does absolutely nothing. I'm not sure if its stuck in an infinite loop or whats going on. I think the issue is coming from my sort method in the `PersonArrayQueue` I believe it is just continually running through the first while loop and never making it to the second for some reason. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm sending the `Comparator` from a `main` method of a demo class like this:

```
personQueue.sort(Person.PersonAgeComparator);
```

My `Person` class:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
   private String firstName;
   private String lastName;
   private int age;

   public Person() {
      firstName = null;
      lastName = null;
      age = 0;
   }

   public Person(String first, String last, int personAge) {
      firstName = first;
      lastName = last;
      age = personAge;
   }

   public void setFirstName(String first) {
      firstName = first;
   }

   public void setLastName(String last) {
      lastName = last;
   }

   public void setAge(int personAge) {
      age = personAge;
   }

   public void setPersonalData(String first, String last, int personAge) {
      firstName = first;
      lastName = last;
      age = personAge;
   }

   public String getName() {
      String name = firstName + " " + lastName;
      return name;
   }

   public String getFirstName() {
      return firstName;
   }

   public String getLastName() {
      return lastName;
   }

   public int getAge() {
      return age;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
      return firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age;
   }

   public void printInfo() {
      System.out.println(firstName + " " + lastName + " " + age);
   }

   public int compareTo(Person comparePerson) {
      int result = lastName.compareTo(comparePerson.lastName);
      return (result != 0 ? result :    firstName.compareTo(comparePerson.firstName));
   }

   public static Comparator<Person> PersonAgeComparator = new Comparator<Person>() {
      @Override
      public int compare(Person firstPerson, Person secondPerson) {  
         if (firstPerson.getAge() < secondPerson.getAge()) {
            return -1;
         } else if (firstPerson.getAge() == secondPerson.getAge()) {
            return 0;
         } else {
            return 1;
         }
      }
   };
}
```

Lastly my `PersonArrayQueue`:

```
import java.util.*;

public final class PersonArrayQueue<T> implements QueueInterface<T> {
   private T[] queue;
   private int front;
   private int end;
   private static final int DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20;
   private Comparator sortComparator;
   private Comparator nameComparator;   

   public PersonArrayQueue() {
      this(DEFAULT_CAPACITY);
   }

   public PersonArrayQueue(int capacity) {
      @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
      T[] tempQueue = (T[]) new Object[capacity];
      queue = tempQueue;
      end = 0;
      front = 0;
   }

   public void enqueue(T anEntry) {
      queue[end] = anEntry;
      end++;
   }

   public T dequeue() {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
         end = 0;
         front = 0;
         return null;
      } else {
         T data = queue[front];
         queue[front] = null;
         front++;
         return data;
      }
   }

   public T getFront() {
      if (isEmpty()) {
         System.out.println("Queue is empty.");
         return null;
      } else {
         T data = queue[front];
         return data;
      }
   }

   public boolean isEmpty() {
      return front == end;
   }

   public void clear() {
      while (!isEmpty()) {
         this.dequeue();
      }
   }

   public int length() {
      return end - front;
   }

   public void display() {
      for (int index = front; index < this.length(); index++) {
         System.out.println(queue[index] + " ");
      }
   }   

   public void sort(Comparator<? super T> theComparator) {  
      sortComparator = theComparator;

      if (queue == null || this.length() == 0) {
         return;
      }

      quickSort(sortComparator, front, end - 1);
   }

   public void quickSort(Comparator aComparator, int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {
      int lower = lowerIndex;
      int upper = higherIndex;
      T pivot = queue[lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2];

      while (lower <= upper) {
         while (aComparator.compare(queue[lower], pivot) > 0) {
            lower++;
         }

         while (aComparator.compare(queue[upper], pivot) < 0) {
            upper--;
         }

         if (aComparator.compare(queue[lower], queue[upper]) >= 0) {
            exchangePositions(lower, upper);
            lower++;
            upper--;
         }
      }

      if (lower < lowerIndex) {
         quickSort(aComparator, lower, higherIndex);
      }

      if (upper > lowerIndex) {
         quickSort(aComparator, lowerIndex, upper);
      }
   }

   public void exchangePositions(int lower, int upper) {
      T temp = queue[lower];
      queue[lower] = queue[upper];
      queue[upper] = temp;
   }
}
```

Comment: You should learn how to debug a code

Comment: You may get more answers if you cut out all the unneeded code by providing a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Not sure, but within quicksort you have recursive calls to quicksort. Add some print statements, maybe a counter, to check for this (no pun intended).

Comment: After putting in some print statements its continually running through the first while loop and never making it beyond that. It doesn't seem to even run any of the while loops within it either.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.